# Run Function after returning from class constructor

Tags: php

So i have a class that is say called *ClassOne* and I call the constructor like so:

```
$myclass = new ClassOne(TRUE);
```

I would like to have the class return the instance of itself then run a command in the background from the class without slowing down the generation of the page that requires the class.

```
class ClassOne {
  function __construct( $bool ) {
    if( $bool ) {
      call_me_in_background( $this->background() );
    }
  }

  function background() {
    //Do stuff...
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't do this in vanilla PHP.  PHP has only one thread of execution, and no ability to background or defer tasks.  Can you tell us what the background task *is*?  There may be other ways, but they aren't appropriate in some cases.

Comment: That's hardly unique to class constructors. You want to run an asynchronous background task, period. There are many more questions about this already...

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run the PHP code asynchronous](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905877/how-to-run-the-php-code-asynchronous)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bphp%5D+asynchronous+background+task

Comment: I was waiting until we knew what the backround task was before picking a dupe.  :p  I really hate having to suggest background HTTP requests, shelling out, or worse, breaking out `pcntl_fork`.  Gimme a nice clean thing that can be fixed by a message queue and a few workers...

Comment: What i want to do is to return the constructor so that the page can be sent/ended for the user and then run a function to cache some stuff.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is to create new thread which will do the action in the background while your code is affected as minumum.
This require you to allow do something from a new thread, just like another request to the server.